# C++ Linked List Node Refers to Itself

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am creating a linked list that holds cards in a deck. It only has a head because I do not need a tail for my uses. When I add the first card, everything works fine, when I add the second card, it sets itself as next and creates an infinite list essentially.

I do not know why this is happening. I have stepped through the code, whenever the addCard() method is called on the second card, the head magically changes to that card without me doing it. It sounds crazy but I can't find any other explanation for it. Any help is much appreciated.

Header

```
#pragma once
#include "Card.h"
class Deck {
public:
    bool isEmpty();
    ~Deck();
    void addCard(Card); //at top
    Card removeCard(); //from top
    void addAllCards(); //All 52 cards
    void print(); //print all the cards
private:
    int count = 0;
    Card* head{ NULL };
};
```

Definitions

```
#include "Deck.h"
#include <iostream>

bool Deck::isEmpty() {
    return this->count == 0;
}


void Deck::addCard(Card card) {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        this->head = &card;
    }
    else {
        card.next = this->head;
        this->head = &card;
    }
    count += 1;
}

Card Deck::removeCard() {
    if (!isEmpty()) {
        count -= 1;
        Card temp = *head;
        head = head->next;
        return temp;
    }
}

void Deck::addAllCards() {
    for (int suit = 0; suit < 4; suit++) {
        for (int rank = 0; rank < 13; rank++) {
            Card newCard = Card(suit, rank);
            this->addCard(newCard);
        }
    }
}

void Deck::print() {
    Card* current = head;
    while (current != NULL) {
        std::cout << current->stringSuitAndRank() << std::endl;
        current = current->next;
    }
}

Deck::~Deck() {
    while (!isEmpty()) {
        removeCard();
    }
}
```

Driver

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Card.h"
#include "Deck.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Card myCard1{ 2, 4 };
    Card myCard2{ 4, 5 };

    {
        Deck myDeck;

        myDeck.addCard(myCard1);
        myDeck.addCard(myCard2);

        cout << endl << "Printing deck..." << endl;
        myDeck.print();

        myDeck.removeCard();
        myDeck.removeCard();

        cout << endl << "Printing deck..." << endl;
        myDeck.print();

        cout << endl << "Adding all cards..." << endl << endl;
        myDeck.addAllCards();

        cout << endl << "Printing deck..." << endl;
        myDeck.print();
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

EDIT: I am also getting a read access violation in the print method when I reach the end of the list. I am assuming it has to do with a nullptr, but help is again aprecciated.

Answer (score 3):

```
void Deck::addCard(Card card) {
```

`card` is a parameter to this class method. Method parameters are effectively local objects in the method. It's no different than declaring an object called `card` in this method. The only difference is that the actual object gets copied from whoever calls this method, but in all other respects it's no different than a variable called `card` that would be declared in this method.

And just like any other variable that gets declared in this method, when it returns this object called `card` gets destroyed. It will be gone. It will be no more. It will cease to exist. It will be an ex-object.

```
this->head = &card;
```

This part of `addCard()` stores a pointer to `card` in the `head` member. So far so good. But, before long, this `card` object will no longer exist. See above. This becomes a pointer to a destroyed object. And the next time `addCard()` gets called, hilarity ensues.

To fix this, you need to reread the chapter in your C++ book that explains how objects in C++ work, when they get created, and when this get destroyed. If your goal for this excersize is to practice implementing link lists yourself, and you do not wish to take advantage of C++ library's containers, then you will need to employ the use of `new` and `delete` to create objects dynamically, so when this method returns those objects will not be gone. They will not be no more. They will not cease to exist. They will not be ex-objects.

Answer (score 1):

Your `addCard` member function is taking `Card` by value:

```
void Deck::addCard(Card card) {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        this->head = &card;
    }
    else {
        card.next = this->head;
        this->head = &card;
    }
    count += 1;
}
```

You're inserting into your linked list the local variable `card` which becomes destroyed when the function terminates.

The fix for this issue could be as simple as:

```
void Deck::addCard(Card &card) { /*...*/ }
                        ^ pass reference
```

However, I don't think so because the caller also allocates these objects in automatic storage; we would just be passing a reference to the caller's local object, rather than a dynamically allocated node.

It is legitimate to put local objects into a linked list, but you have to make sure they are removed from the list before they "go out of scope". A situation like the following is possible:

```
{
  list_class li;
  node_class n1, n2, n3;
  li.add_by_reference(n1, n2, n3);
  // OK? maybe.
  // here n1, n2, n3 destructors get called then li.
  // if li doesn't touch the nodes, everything is cool
}
```

But this is not correct:

```
{
  list_class li;

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    node_class n;
    li.add_by_reference(n);
  }

  // A new n object is created and destroyed for each loop iteration.
  // The list still has links to a destroyed node, and a new one is
  // being added to it.
}
```

The situation in your program (specifically, in `Deck::addAllCards`) resembles the second example here. The fix for the second example would be to dynamically allocate:

```
li.add_by_reference(*new node_class);
```

Now we have a memory leak, though; the destructor of `list_class` probably has no idea that the nodes are dynamically allocated and doesn't free them.

Suppose we put in code to free the nodes before the function terminates, like:

```
while (!li.empty()) {
  node_class *pn = li.dequeue_head();
  delete pn;
}
```

There is a problem with exception safety though; if `new` throws, the function will be abandoned without executing this loop; only the destructor for `li` will be called.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I feel very stupid now lol. Perhaps you can help me with why I get a read access violation in the print() method?

Comment: But by adding a reference to `addCard` you are only saving the address of a stack object created in the `AddAllCards` function. It will quickly become invalid. A better solution would be to create the objects on the heap to begin with, but that requires some serious redesign of this code.

Comment: @Matzi This is covered in the edits I made just in the last 30 seconds.

Comment: @Kaz I can see it now. However this is still not a solution, only a highlight of the problem.