# insertion at the end of linked list function not working

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, linked-list

I don't know where I am wrong, when I debugged the code I found out that the 'new node' address is 'new node' address, **basically the new node is referring to itself**

```
void insertend(struct node *parent, int item)
{
    while (parent->addr != NULL)
        parent = parent->addr;

    struct node new_node;
    new_node.a = item;

    parent->addr = &new_node;
    parent->addr->addr = NULL;
}
```

Comment: `new_node` is a local variable. It goes out of scope and is destroyed when `insertend` returns, leaving `parent` holding a dangling pointer.

Comment: *"I found out that the 'new node' address is 'new node' address"* -- this... looks rather tautological. Did you perhaps mean *"I found out that `new_node.addr` is `&new_node`"* (one "address" meaning the `addr` field, while the other means "the address of")?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ Linked List Node Refers to Itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58653077/c-linked-list-node-refers-to-itself)

Comment: Make this a constructor for struct `node` and use `new` to allocate new nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> void insertend(struct node *parent, int item)
> {
>    while (parent->addr != NULL)
>        parent = parent->addr;
>
>    struct node new_node;
>    new_node.a = item;
>
>    parent->addr = &new_node;
>    parent->addr->addr = NULL;
> }
> ```

The lifetime of `new_node` is limited to the function. Once that function returns, it is no longer valid.

In order to circumvent this, it is necessary to dynamically allocate memory for  `new_node`. Of course, as already pointed out, this means explicitly deallocating the memory eventually.

*Note: as this is C++ rather than C, we do not need to add `struct` to the front of the type in use, and `NULL` is better spelled `nullptr`.*

```
void insertend(node *parent, int item)
{
    while (parent->addr != nullptr)
        parent = parent->addr;

    node *new_node = new node;
    new_node.a = item;

    parent->addr = new_node;
    parent->addr->addr = nullptr;
}
```

As C++ structs are just classes with default public access, it's also worth noting we could implement this as a member function. Something like:

```
template <typename T>
struct Node {
    T value;
    Node<T> *next;

    void append(T val) {
        Node<T> * temp = this;
        while (temp->next != nullptr) {
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        temp->next = new Node<T>;
        temp->next->value = val;
        temp->next->next = nullptr;
    }
};

int main() {
    auto n = Node<int>();
    n.value = 27;

    n.append(42);
    n.append(34);

    for (Node<int> *t = &n; t != nullptr; t = t->next) {
        std::cout << t->value << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The next step would be implementing a constructor and destructor.

One more thing to keep in mind is that getting to the end of a list this way is O(n) time complexity. Doing it over and over again is costly. If you have `Node::append` return a pointer to the new `Node`, then you can call `append` on that.

```
template <typename T>
struct Node {
    T value;
    Node<T> *next;

    Node<T> *append(T val) {
        Node<T> * temp = this;
        while (temp->next != nullptr) {
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        temp->next = new Node<T>;
        temp->next->value = val;
        temp->next->next = nullptr;

        return temp->next;
    }
};

int main() {
    auto n = Node<int>();
    n.value = 27;

    auto n2 = n.append(42);
    n2 = n2->append(34);
    n2 = n2->append(15);

    for (Node<int> *t = &n; t != nullptr; t = t->next) {
        std::cout << t->value << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks, pal
I actually figured it on that day I posted the question. I now realize what is the use of HEAP memory.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure what the `addr` refers to, but I would assume it points to the next node in the linked list. In your code, there needs to be another node to use as a temporary node, because the parent node keeps being reassigned, and the previous items are lost. We also need to check that the parent node is not `NULL`.

```
void insertend(struct node **parent, int item)
{
    node *new_node = new node;
    new_node->a = item;
    new_node->addr = NULL;

    if(*parent == NULL)
    {
      *parent = new_node;
    }
    else
    {
      node *temp = *parent;
      while (temp->addr != NULL)
          temp = temp->addr;

      temp->addr = new_node;
    }
}
```

The if statement checks whether the parent node is `NULL`. If `true`, then we assign `parent` node to `new_node`. If `false`, then we go to the end of the list and assign the next node in the list to `new_node`.

Comment: `parent = new_node;` won't do what you think since `parent` is a copy of the pointer that is passed in. It would need to be passed as a double pointer or a reference to a pointer to be visible outside the function.

Comment: Good catch. I updated the answer to reflect that

Comment: A reference would be easier and more C++ like. Of course if the original code really embraced C++ there wouldn't be `struct` scattered all over the place where it isn't necessary. *shrug* With the double pointer you're now missing a dereference everywhere `parent` is used.

Answer (score 0):

As Igor correctly pointed out, your new node gets destroyed when the function finishes. So, in this context you could just allocate memory. You can use the `new` operator for this. However, you would need to explicitly free the memory, *eventually.*

```
void insertend(struct node *parent, int item)
{
    while (parent->addr != NULL)
        parent = parent->addr;

    struct * new_node = new node;

    new_node->a = item;
    parent->addr = new_node;
    parent->addr->addr = NULL;
}
```